# How to convert Arabic Presentation Forms-B to normal Arabic Characters with bash?

Tags: unicode

When I convert a pdf file to a text file using pdftotext the Arabic characters appear in non-convenient way like this ﻌ, how can I convert all of these characters to normal Arabic Characters?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

Note: You may need to alter some lines like ا, ه,ي and لا if you want the original text. but you can use this if you want to avoid people mistakes relating to these letters.

```
cat file.txt | sed 's/[ﺀﺁﺂﺃﺄﺅﺆﺇﺈﺉﺊﺋﺌﺍﺎ]/ا/g;'\
's/[ﺏﺐﺑﺒ]/ب/g;'\
's/[ﺓﺔ]/ه/g;'\
's/[ﺕﺖﺗﺘ]/ت/g;'\
's/[ﺙﺚﺛﺜ]/ث/g;'\
's/[ﺝﺞﺟﺠ]/ج/g;'\
's/[ﺡﺢﺣﺤ]/ح/g;'\
's/[ﺥﺦﺧﺨ]/خ/g;'\
's/[ﺩﺪ]/د/g;'\
's/[ﺫﺬ]/ذ/g;'\
's/[ﺭﺮ]/ر/g;'\
's/[ﺯﺰ]/ز/g;'\
's/[ﺱﺲﺳﺴ]/س/g;'\
's/[ﺵﺶﺷﺸ]/ش/g;'\
's/[ﺹﺺﺻﺼ]/ص/g;'\
's/[ﺽﺾﺿﻀ]/ض/g;'\
's/[ﻁﻂﻃﻄ]/ط/g;'\
's/[ﻅﻆﻇﻈ]/ظ/g;'\
's/[ﻉﻊﻋﻌ]/ع/g;'\
's/[ﻍﻎﻏﻐ]/غ/g;'\
's/[ﻑﻒﻓﻔ]/ف/g;'\
's/[ﻕﻖﻗﻘ]/ق/g;'\
's/[ﻙﻚﻛﻜ]/ك/g;'\
's/[ﻝﻞﻟﻠ]/ل/g;'\
's/[ﻡﻢﻣﻤ]/م/g;'\
's/[ﻥﻦﻧﻨ]/ن/g;'\
's/[ﻩﻪﻫﻬ]/ه/g;'\
's/[ﻭﻮ]/و/g;'\
's/[ﻯﻰﻱﻲﻳﻴ]/ي/g;'\
's/[ﻵﻶﻷﻸﻹﻺﻻﻼ]/لا/g;'
```